# Fotonic depth camera in ROS

Tags: ros, camera-driver, 3dcamera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I'm now trying to use a Fotonic depth camera in ROS and the camera is not covered by ROS. They do have a Linux API and they already provide some SDK for me.

http://www.fotonic.com/product/fotonic-e-serie-16w/

It seems that I have to write a driver on my own, but I have no experience on this. Anyone has written this driver before? Or is there any where that I can learn how to start my work?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235626/fotonic-depth-camera-in-ros/) by [blueflame](https://answers.ros.org/users/26744/blueflame/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2016-05-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! There is a ROS implementation but it has some issues related to memory leaks and filter tuning.

https://github.com/RobotnikAutomation/fotonic_3dcamera

Hope this helps. I will try to improve this package at late January.

---

Originally posted by [dagarzonr](https://answers.ros.org/users/25962/dagarzonr/) with karma: 26 on 2016-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for your answer. I've finish mine in June 2016.
Here is my own work. I pushed it on GitHub recently.
It publishes the ROS topic in 30Hz. Hope I can help other people.

https://github.com/BoomFan/fotonic_wrapper.git

---

Originally posted by [blueflame](https://answers.ros.org/users/26744/blueflame/) with karma: 35 on 2017-03-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [boooooosh](https://answers.ros.org/users/31171/boooooosh/) on 2017-07-25**:
Hi, thanks for the work! A question: have you ever met the problem of NOT able to retrieve the point cloud? The device closed due to a error saying 'Error in header retrieval', I am not sure whether I have to change some part of the code to make this work?

**Comment by [blueflame](https://answers.ros.org/users/26744/blueflame/) on 2017-07-25**:
Hi. It's been a while since my first version of the code, so I kind of forgot what I actually did. But I think you are right. I did compile their official driver and copy them into "/usr/local/" directory.

**Comment by [blueflame](https://answers.ros.org/users/26744/blueflame/) on 2017-07-25**:
This is what I did after compiling:

cd /usr/local/

sudo mkdir -p fotonic

sudo cp -r ~/Downloads/fz-linux-api_x64/include/*.* /usr/local/fotonic

sudo cp -r ~/Downloads/fz-linux-api_x64/lib/*.* /usr/local/fotonic

**Comment by [boooooosh](https://answers.ros.org/users/31171/boooooosh/) on 2017-07-25**:
Many thx! I done by setting the link_library to the local lib folder. That makes everyone happy!